# Website with https, Google Analytics for long time with http... can I change it?

Tags: http, https, analytics

and its URL is 'secured' with SSL (with httpS://mywebsite.nl).

However, I found out that, for a long time, at Google Analytics, I use http://mywebsite.nl, ('non-secured') at my property and view's 'Default URL'.

I have two questions:

1. Did I miss data because I used http instead of https in the property and view's Default URL?
2. Can I CHANGE the http to httpS (in Google Analytics property/view) without problem, or do I lose historical data because of that? (This probably also depends on answer of Q1...) Or should I ADD a new property and/or view with https Default URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. you didn't
2. you don't lose the historical data, feel free to change it.

That "default url" is for your convenience. you can do anything with it. That's just what GA uses to form full URLs from page paths only. Instead of using the hostname dimension there.

Also, GA is gracious enough to warn you whenever you can do significant changes to your core data.